# How to show the selected option value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was able to append values in an array to the select option. When I do that I am not able to see the text value(A1) in the selection box. But when I use an alert box it shows A1 as the selected option.

My jQUERY CODE:

```
var route=['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A7',......,'A50']
$.each(route, function(key, value) {
 $('#room').append($('<option>', { value : key }).text(value)); 

if (!$("#room option:selected").length)
$("#room option[value='0']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

This is my html code:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
<select name="room" id="room">  
</select>          
</div>
```

Can anyone help me on this one?

Comment: Too many `ooo`'s in your selector. - `!$("#rooom option:selected")`

Comment: there are a few errors in your code. Is it `route` or `A_Route`? You are missing the closing `});` on your each block.

Comment: I did a copy/paste into jsFiddle, fixed the few code issues, and it worked just fine, so I'm going to guess you are getting scripting errors which are causing things to not show up

Comment: Oh yeah! sorry for typing errors. Made some edits!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
var route=['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A7','A50'], html;
$.each(route, function(key, value) {
  html += '<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>';
});
$('#room').append(html);

if ($("#room").val() !== '0') {
  $("#room").val(0); // using .val() will select the correct option for you, based on it's value attribute
} ​
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/tyPFu/

Comment: @Ben: Your ans is working fine on jsfiddle but it is still not showing the A1 value on my browser.

Comment: put the code in $(document).ready(function(){}); or $(function(){}); or use any function call